# Apache does not load Imagick PHP extension

Tags: php, macos, apache, imagick

I have this problem with Apache on Mac OS:

I installed Imagick extension but can't use it from Apache. The phpinfo page doesn't show the module information. However, the CLI version does show the module and both use the same php.ini file.

I'm using XAMPP for Mac and I have installed extensions before but for some reason Apache doesn't load the extension.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.